# JavaScript: Editable combobox -- unable to edit first entry

Tags: javascript, combobox

I am using the editable combobox from http://chakrabarty.com/pp_editable_dropdown.html in my application. However I have a requirement for multiple comboboxes to be created on events due to which I have to write the combobox in JavaScript.
The combobox works, but the first entry which is editable is not allowing edit.

Original html code:

```
<select name="lstDropDown_A" id="lstDropDown_A" style="" onKeyDown="fnKeyDownHandler_A(this, event);" onKeyUp="fnKeyUpHandler_A(this, event); return false;" onKeyPress = "return fnKeyPressHandler_A(this, event);"  onChange="fnChangeHandler_A(this);" onFocus="fnFocusHandler_A(this);">
    <option value="" style="font-family:Courier,monospace;color:#ff0000;background-color:#ffff00;">--?--</option>
    <option>Editable Dropdown</option>
    <option>Combobox</option>
    <option>Tiger</option>
    <option>Software</option>
    <option>India</option>
</select>
```

My JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var element  = document.createElement("select");
    element.name = "lstDropDown_A";
    element.id   = "lstDropDown_A";

    var option;
    options = ['--?--', 'Editable Dropdown', 'Combobox', 'Tiger', 'Software', 'India'];
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        option = document.createElement("option");
        if (i == 0) {
            option.value = "";
        }
        option.text = options[i];
        element.appendChild(option);
    }
    element.addEventListener('keydown',  fnKeyDownHandler_A);
    element.addEventListener('keyup',    fnKeyUpHandler_A);
    element.addEventListener('keypress', fnKeyPressHandler_A);
    element.addEventListener('change',   fnChangeHandler_A);
    element.addEventListener('focus',    fnFocusHandler_A);

    document.forms[0].appendChild(element);
</script>
```

One thing I don't have is return false; after call to fnKeyUpHandler_A.

Comment: it is not work with function undefined error, as there is only function call and no function part in your code to perform task

Comment: I have only posted the JavaScript equivalent snippet of the combobox html. I have all the event handler functions and global variables in my html file. Without comments, the full file is around 350 lines, so I haven't posted it here.

Comment: could you please create jsfiddle or codepen to debug easily ?

Comment: Could not create jsfiddle due to js code inside html body. But I have the entire file on github -> https://gist.github.com/mh-github/8ab87dc154318ac7a3b733fe5eb95598
You can see that in the first combo box, the first entry is editable, where as in the second combo box it is not.